# php return two values in loop from a function

Tags: php

```
add_shortcode( 'cpostgridelement', 'cpostgridelementFunc'  );
function cpostgridelementFunc( $atts ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'cpttypee' => 'member','templatetypee'=>'memberTemplate','postsidd'=>2 ), $atts));

// if($postsid){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2, // id of a page, post, or custom type
        'post_type' =>$cpttypee,
        'order'    => 'Desc',
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts()) :
            $custom_query->the_post();
            $title      =   get_the_title();
            $postLink   =   get_permalink();
            $f_page_images = get_field('image');
            $board_member_title = get_field('board_member_title');
            $board_member_email = get_field('email');
            $board_member_phone = get_field('phone');
            $board_member_description = get_field('board_member_description');
            $imgId = wp_get_attachment_image($f_page_images,'thumbnail');

        $collectInfoo = array();
            $collectInfoo[]="<div class='annual_cntct vc_staff_addon'>
                <div class='annual_top brd_membr'><div class='annual_top_inr stf_mmbr_inr'>
                        <div class='lft_annual_sdbr col'>".$imgId."
                        </div>
                        <div class='rght_annual_sdbr col'>
                            <h4 class='bld_anul'>".$title."</h4>
                            <h4 class='vc_gry'>".$board_member_title."</h4>
                            <h4 class='vc_gry'>".$board_member_phone."</h4>
                            <h4 class='vc_gry'>".$board_member_email."</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clear'></div>
                    </div></div></div>";

                    endwhile;
                    return $collectInfoo;

    endif;
// }
// else{
    //no post id entered
    // echo "No Post Id entered";
// }
}
```

I am trying to get 2 posts. But the problem is if i use return it gives me just 1 post and echo can not be used here.

Comment: `$collectInfoo` should be defined outside `while`

Comment: Personally, I now think its bad to return HTML in functions. You should return values and add HTML as of when it's needed.. Just in case you need to reuse functions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**EDIT:**
I went ahead and removed the HTML you're returning in the array. Just echo the HTML in your loop when you call this function.

Although you resolved your own question, I would consider using something like this.

```
add_shortcode( 'cpostgridelement', 'cpostgridelementFunc'  );
function cpostgridelementFunc( $atts ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'cpttypee' => 'member','templatetypee'=>'memberTemplate','postsidd'=>2 ), $atts));

// if($postsid){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2, // id of a page, post, or custom type
        'post_type' =>$cpttypee,
        'order'    => 'Desc',
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    $collectInfoo = array();
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts()) :
        $custom_query->the_post();
        $title      =   get_the_title();
        $postLink   =   get_permalink();
        $f_page_images = get_field('image');
        $board_member_title = get_field('board_member_title');
        $board_member_email = get_field('email');
        $board_member_phone = get_field('phone');
        $board_member_description = get_field('board_member_description');
        $imgId = wp_get_attachment_image($f_page_images,'thumbnail');


       $collectInfoo[]= array("thumbnail"=>$imgId,"board_member_title"=>$board_member_title,"phone"=>$board_member_phone,"board_member_description"=>$board_member_description);
        endwhile;
        return $collectInfoo;
    endif;
// }
// else{
//no post id entered
// echo "No Post Id entered";
// }
}
```

Comment: It outputs the word "Array"

Comment: I am able to resolve this myself. by changibg $collectInfoo[] to$collectInfoo.

Comment: Cool, as long as it works. But go ahead and see my updated answer as well. @user930026